# How do I use regex with svn move?

Tags: svn

How do I recursively call `svn mv` on all files, but also use regex to rename each file name? In my case I want to remove the "C" prefix to all .cpp and .h file names.

Answer (score 0):

If using Linux, and want to remove "C" from the start of file names for .cpp files, you can do the following:

```
for i in $(find . -regex '.*\/C.*\.cpp'); do svn mv `perl -e 'my $s=$ARGV[0]; $s=~m/(.*\/)C(.*)/; print "$s $1$2"' "$i"`; done
```